# How to make a N×N matrix each of i-th row and i-th column having all the elements 1 to 2N-1?

Tags: algorithm

This question was asked as a puzzle in one Book of Puzzles by RS AGGARWAL, which stated the problem as to build an order N matrix where each i'th row and i'th column combined have all the elements from 1 to 2N-1.

For instance, for N=2

```
[3,2]
[1,3]
```

I want to know when is an answer possible for it for which values of N it is possible to make a matrix and how to make it? and write code for it

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I don't know the Logic ! I want to write the code for this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [constructing a square matrix of edge N, and its element should not be same across same row and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630967/constructing-a-square-matrix-of-edge-n-and-its-element-should-not-be-same-acros)

Comment: @baker it is the same question, but the single answer is invalid. So there is thus no answer to this question so far

Comment: @chmike That doesn't mean there should be a new question, just a better answer on the existing question.

Comment: @beaker should I move my answer to the other question ?

Comment: @chmike I don't think the question should be answered at all (or at least not for a couple of days) because it is part of an [ongoing programming competition](https://www.codechef.com/JAN20B/problems/DFMTRX) in violation of their [code of conduct](https://www.codechef.com/codeofconduct) (see point 6).

Comment: @beaker, wasn't aware of this competition. Beside I found out my answer was wrong. A solution exist for N=6. I thus deleted my answer.

Comment: @beaker if I see/understand it right the point 6 does not prohibit the sharing of code but just discourage it instead ... to avoid responsibility of protecting your code in case of miss-use or theft... also OP states a different source of the problem (book) I am sure you can find a competition for many problems ...

Comment: @chmike would like to see your valid 6x6 matrix  may be it will hint me how to expand power of two solution ... (I am too lazy to play with the numbers manually)

Comment: @Spektre Sorry, point 8. "Do not ask or discuss any aspect of any CodeChefs’ problem during an ongoing contest on any other platform, online or offline." My mistake. Naturally, Stack Overflow members are not bound by this condition and can answer if they wish. But if this question *is* from a competition, I would prefer that readers be aware so they can make an informed decision as whether they want to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has simple solution for square matrices where `n` is power of 2 so `n=1,2,4,8,16,...` do not ask me why there surely is some math proof for it ...

The algorithm to create such matrix is easy:

1. **clear matrix (with `0`)**
2. **loop `i` through all values `i=1,2,3...2n-1`**
3. **for each `i` find all locations where `i` matrix is not yet filled (`0`) and there is not `i` present in row and column**

   fill the position with `i` and repeat until no such location found.

In C++ something like this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int n=8;
int m[n][n];
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// compute histogram u[n+n] of values per ith row,col of m[n][n]
void hist_rst(int *u                  ) { for (int j=0;j<n+n;j++) u[j]=0; }
void hist_row(int *u,int m[n][n],int i) { for (int j=0;j<n;j++) u[m[j][i]]=1; }
void hist_col(int *u,int m[n][n],int i) { for (int j=0;j<n;j++) u[m[i][j]]=1; }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void matrix_init(int m[n][n])
    {
    int i,x,y,h[n][n+n];
    // clear matrix (unused cells)
    for (x=0;x<n;x++)
     for (y=0;y<n;y++)
      m[x][y]=0;
    // clear histograms
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) hist_rst(h[i]);
    // try to fill values 1..2n-1
    for (i=1;i<n+n;i++)
        {
        // find free position
        for (x=0;x<n;x++) if (!h[x][i])
         for (y=0;y<n;y++) if (!h[y][i])
          if (!m[x][y])
            {
            // set cell
            m[x][y]=i;
            h[x][i]=1;
            h[y][i]=1;
            break;
            }
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here few outputs:

```
  1

  1  3
  2  1

  1  5  6  7
  2  1  7  6
  3  4  1  5
  4  3  2  1
            
  1  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
  2  1 11 10 13 12 15 14
  3  4  1  9 14 15 12 13
  4  3  2  1 15 14 13 12
  5  6  7  8  1  9 10 11
  6  5  8  7  2  1 11 10
  7  8  5  6  3  4  1  9
  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

for non power of 2 matrices you could use backtracking but take in mind even 4x4 matrix will have many iterations to check ... so some heuristics would need to be in place to make it possible in finite time... as brute force is `(n+n)^(n*n)` so for `n=4` there are `281474976710656` combinations to check ...

**[edit1] genere&test solution for even n**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int n=6;
int m[n][n];
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// compute histogram u[n+n] of values per ith row,col of m[n][n]
void hist_rst(int *u                  ) { for (int j=0;j<n+n;j++) u[j]=0; }
void hist_row(int *u,int m[n][n],int i) { for (int j=0;j<n;j++) u[m[j][i]]=1; }
void hist_col(int *u,int m[n][n],int i) { for (int j=0;j<n;j++) u[m[i][j]]=1; }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void matrix_init2(int m[n][n])  // brute force
    {
    int x,y,a,ax[(n*n)>>1],ay[(n*n)>>1],an,u[n+n];
    // clear matrix (unused cells)
    for (x=0;x<n;x++)
     for (y=0;y<n;y++)
      m[x][y]=0;
    // main diagonal 1,1,1,1...
    for (x=0;x<n;x++) m[x][x]=1;
    // 1st row 1,2,3...n
    for (x=1;x<n;x++) m[x][0]=x+1;
    // cells for brute force
    for (an=0,x=0;x<n;x++)
     for (y=0;y<x;y++)
      if (!m[x][y])
        {
        ax[an]=x;
        ay[an]=y;
        an++;
        m[x][y]=2;
        }
    // brute force attack values 2,3,4,5,...,n-1
    for (;;)
        {
        // increment solution
        for (a=0;a<an;a++)
            {
            x=ax[a];
            y=ay[a];
            m[x][y]++;
            if (m[x][y]<=n) break;
            m[x][y]=2;
            }
        if (a>=an) break;   // no solution
        // test
        for (x=0;x<n;x++)
            {
            hist_rst(u);
            hist_col(u,m,x);
            hist_row(u,m,x);
            for (y=1;y<=n;y++) if (!u[y]) { y=0; x=n; break; }
            }
        if (y) break;       // solution found
        }

    // mirror other triangle
    for (x=0;x<n;x++)
     for (y=0;y<x;y++)
      m[y][x]=m[x][y]+n-1;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

however its slow so do not try to go with `n>6` without more optimizations/better heuristics... for now it is using triangle+mirror and diagonal + first row hard-coded heuristics.

maybe somehow exploit the fact that each iterated value will be placed `n/2` times could speed this up more but too lazy to implement it ...

Here output for `n=6`:

```
[  52.609 ms]
  1  2  3  4  5  6
  7  1  6  5  3  4
  8 11  1  2  4  5
  9 10  7  1  6  3
 10  8  9 11  1  2
 11  9 10  8  7  1
```

iterating through 5^10 cases ...

Comment: It (first algo) takes more than 1 minute for n=2048. I doubt that this is the expected solution. It should execute in less than 1 second for n up to 2000.

Comment: @chmike may be find out some symmetry that can convert solution of `n` into `n+1` ... however OP does not mention any time  constrains ... nor optimal solution ... Also the algo 1 is not optimized at all ... the histograms can be speeded up considerably ...

Comment: the time constrain is given in the code chef page https://www.codechef.com/JAN20B/problems/DFMTRX

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide the direct solution of power two sized matrix

Answer (score 0):

As requested by Spektre, here is the 6x6 matrix.

I an interesting property that may be used as heuristic. We need only to solve a triangular matrix because the other half can be easily deduced. We fill the upper (or lower) half of the matrix by values from 1 to n only. We can then complete the matrix by using the property that a[j][i] = 2n + 1 - a[i][j].

Another property I found is that there is a trivial way to place 1, 2 and N in the matrix. The values 1 are all on the diagonal, the values 2 and N are next to the diagonal at a step 2.

Finally, another thing I found is that matrix with odd N have no solutions. It is because the value in a[i][j] belongs to row and column i and row and column j. We thus need an even number of row and columns to store all values.

Here is the 6x6 matrix I found manually.

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6
11  1  6  5  3  4
10  7  1  2  4  5
 9  8 11  1  6  3
 8 10  9  7  1  2
 7  9  8 10 11  1
```

As we can see 2 + 11 = 6 + 7 = 3 + 10 = 13 = 2*6+1.

Here is a 4x4 matrix

```
1 2 3 4
7 1 4 3
6 5 1 2
5 6 7 1
```

Here again 2 + 7 = 4 + 5 = 3 + 6 = 9 = 2*4+1

It is possible to have other permutations of values >N, but with the 2N+1 property we can trivially deduce one triangular matrix from the other.

**EDIT**

Here is a solution for power two sized matrix. The matrix of size 2048x2048 is generated in 57ms (without printing).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int **newMatrix(int n) {
    int **m = calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    m[0] = calloc(n*n, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        m[i] = m[0]+i*n;
    return m;
}

void printMatrix(int **m, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%3d ", m[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void fillPowerTwoMatrix(int **m, int n) {
    // return if n is not power two
    if (n < 0 || n&(n-1) != 0)
        return;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        m[0][i] = i+1;
    for (int w = 1; w < n; w *= 2)
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k += 2*w)
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
                for (int j = k; j < k+w; j++) {
                    m[i+w][j] = m[i][j+w];
                    m[i+w][j+w] = m[i][j];
                }
    int k = 2*n+1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            m[i][j] = k - m[j][i];
}

int main() {
    int n = 16;
    int **m = newMatrix(n);
    fillPowerTwoMatrix(m, n);
    printMatrix(m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the matrix 16x16. As can be seen there is a symmetry that is exploited to efficiently generate the matrix.

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16 
 31   1   4   3   6   5   8   7  10   9  12  11  14  13  16  15 
 30  29   1   2   7   8   5   6  11  12   9  10  15  16  13  14 
 29  30  31   1   8   7   6   5  12  11  10   9  16  15  14  13 
 28  27  26  25   1   2   3   4  13  14  15  16   9  10  11  12 
 27  28  25  26  31   1   4   3  14  13  16  15  10   9  12  11 
 26  25  28  27  30  29   1   2  15  16  13  14  11  12   9  10 
 25  26  27  28  29  30  31   1  16  15  14  13  12  11  10   9 
 24  23  22  21  20  19  18  17   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
 23  24  21  22  19  20  17  18  31   1   4   3   6   5   8   7 
 22  21  24  23  18  17  20  19  30  29   1   2   7   8   5   6 
 21  22  23  24  17  18  19  20  29  30  31   1   8   7   6   5 
 20  19  18  17  24  23  22  21  28  27  26  25   1   2   3   4 
 19  20  17  18  23  24  21  22  27  28  25  26  31   1   4   3 
 18  17  20  19  22  21  24  23  26  25  28  27  30  29   1   2 
 17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31   1
```

Comment: another heuristics might be that all the values (except diagonal 1) are present n/2 times which also limits the n to even numbers... I managed to make genere&test solution that works (using triangle and diagonal + first row hard-coded heuristics) but even for `n=6` it take `[  52.578 ms]` so for `n=7` and higher it would take forever ... :( ... n=1,2,4,6 gives correct solutions